# Outlook Web Add-In Deployment

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Hi basically I want to deploy office outlook web add-in to office store I've created my add-in but i'm unable to deploy it please guide me how I deploy it.

I've read [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish#outlook-add-in-deployment) Microsoft article but not understand rather then centralized deployment **(Office 365 admin center)** I need to deploy on Microsoft office store for all outlook users.

Comment: What does " i'm unable to deploy" mean?

Comment: You don’t need the app to be on the Office Store in order to deploy it to a company.  You just need to host your application in a permanent location, and deploy your app’s manifest to the organization.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/use-the-centralized-deployment-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-add-ins

Comment: The link to the doc you provided lists several methods to deploy your add-in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish). One of the options is if you want to add your add-in to the Office Store (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center)

Comment: Thanks for reply
I'm not want to centralized deployment i want to deploy on Microsft Store they said to me make developer account and submit your code (Microsoft AppSource via Partner Center) Where I need to submit source any URL ? There is any verification process ?

Comment: There are instructions on how to submit you add-in to the store here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center This page details the approval/certification process and how to create a developer account and submit your solution to Microsoft AppSource via Partner Center.

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions on how to submit you add-in to the store here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center This page details the approval/certification process and how to create a developer account and submit your solution to Microsoft AppSource via Partner Center.